# Lighting went out in half of house?

Tags: electrical

I was in my room today with my laptop and phone plugged in and the ceiling fan and light on when I heard a loud pop near the light and fan. All the power in my room went out, as well as the second bedroom and the master, but the rest of the house is just fine. I reset the tripped breaker, which was just for the second and third bedroom. The master should have been fine if it was just a breaker problem, but none of them are still working.

After flipping all the breakers off and on, nothing changed. What's weird is that my phone and laptop have both been plugged in like that before with no problems. The house is about 12 years old, but we seem to be having problems with the electricity, as in the past few months, the fire alarm has randomly gone off a few times and the garage door opened without anyone pressing a button. Anyone have any ideas as to what this could be?

Answer (score 4):

Often the electrician will have multiple taps in a ceiling light or fan.

The popping sound is probably where the problem is, and resetting the breaker did nothing because the popping ( fault to ground ) broke the circuit.

I would not recommend this for a DIY project because damaged wires and connections need expert eyes.

But the good news is you've probably saved the electrician some leg work hunting down the source of the problem, and you some money paying their time.

Smoke alarms need to be replaced every 10 years so that may need to be done since you mentioned the house is over 10 years old.

Garage doors opening on their own shouldn't have anything to do with power quality, but more of a circuit board defect, faulty keypad button or similar.